# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model> Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List 
Model :

```
  public class UsersViewModels
{
    public AspNetUser aspNetUser { get; set; }
    public List<FuelerAppointment> appointmentslist { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UsersViewModels();
        model.appointmentslist = db.AspNetUsers.Where(
        user => db.FuelerAppointments.Any(f => f.AspNetUserId == user.Id))
       .Select(user => user.UserName).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/cansharp39t-convert-listltanonymoustypesharp1gt-to-listltmodelgt

Answer (score 2):

Your query is selecting a list of the string contains UserNames. And you can not convert List of string to List of FuelerAppointment. You should change to:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UsersViewModels();
        model.appointmentslist = db.AspNetUsers.Where(
        user => db.FuelerAppointments.Any(f => f.AspNetUserId == user.Id))
       .Select(user => user.FuelerAppointments).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a list of UserNames, so you will end up with a `List<string>` and your property is a `List<FuelerAppointement>`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't let you to do this. You declared your list as `List<Object>` you can't assign it to `String`. you need to change list if you have `username` properly in `FuelerAppointment`

I have tow models same bellow.

```
 public class FuelerAppointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int AspNetUserId { get; set; }
}

public class AspNetUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and viewModel:

```
public class UsersViewModels
{
    public List<FuelerAppointment> appointmentslist { get; set; }
}
```

I think bellow code can help you

```
 [HttpGet]
    public UsersViewModels Get()
    {
        var model = new UsersViewModels
        {
            appointmentslist = (from user in _dbContext.AspNetUsers
                join fuelerAppointment in _dbContext.FuelerAppointments on user.Id equals fuelerAppointment.AspNetUserId
                select new FuelerAppointment { UserName = user.UserName }).ToList()
        };

        return model;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried but I got error : System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'Startupfuels.Data.FuelerAppointment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: but i can do it